# 3d max view rotation around static point

Tags: 3ds-max

Orthographic view.
I select object A and rotate view it by viewcube. It is rotated relative to the center of object A - it is what I need. Then I select object B and try to rotate view, but it is rotated relative to the center of coordinates and I can't see my object, I should to use **Zoom Extens** button.
How to fix point of rotation for all objects?

Comment: where is the mathematical center of your object? Im pretty sure its at origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3ds max assumes the center of your view is the object you have selected. Select both objects and it will take the center of both of those objects and allow you to orbit around them.

This link may also provide some useful information about navigating(specifically orbiting) in 3d space.

[3DS max Documentation](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-6DA741AB-9941-4957-903A-4B998C1C65E7.htm,topicNumber=d30e571648)